# How to get a JPA-persisted String[] column by ResultSet#getString() in JDBC?

Tags: arrays, jpa, jdbc, entity

I want to store multiple checkbox values in a single DB column. I don't want to store in a seperate table with `@OneToMany`.

This is the JPA entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="COOK")
...
@Column(name="ARRAY_FOOD" )
private String[] arrayFood;
...getter and setters...
```

Here are the checkbox values (JSF):

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{foodBean.selectedModel.arrayFood}" layout="lineDirection">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="FISH"       itemValue="FISH"           />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="SOUP"       itemValue="SOUP"           />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="CAKE"       itemValue="CAKE"           />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="1/2 WATER"  itemValue="1/2 WATER"      />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="BANANA 1KG" itemValue="BANANA 1KG"     />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

JPA stores the submitted checked values as follows:

```
Column Name Data Type   Sample Data
----------------------------------------
ARRAY_FOOD  RAW (255)   ACED0005757200135B4C6A6176612E6C616E672E537472696E673BADD256E7E91D7B4702000078700000000174000141
```

How can I get the original array by `ResultSet` in aother program?

```
String array = rs.getString("ARRAY_FOOD");  // ???????????
```

Or how can I format it in a understandable format like so in other program I can split it by char like ";" :

```
FISH;SOUP;BANANA 1KG
```

Comment: *I don't want to store in a seperate table with OneToMany*: you should really reconsider this. Otherwise you end up in a denormalized and hard-to-use datamodel.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. The reason is that I have a large set of data and every `Cook` `Entity` will have at least 10 `Foods`. The program should be fast and joining will effect the performance.

Can't I have a column `FOOD (in DB)` and `ARRAY_FOOD (Not in DB)` and It will write it in format `X;Y;Z;` to `FOOD` and read it into array `ARRAY_FOOD`. So in JSF I will use `ARRAY_FOOD` but when writing it will write to DB's `FOOD` Column?

Answer (score 0):

By default serializable types that are not supported database types are serialized.  You would need to use Java serialization to get these types back outside of JPA.

You could instead use a @Converter to convert the array as you wish if using EclipseLink.

You could also use get/set method to convert the value, see,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Basic_Attributes#Conversion